# Heidi Sql Trace doesn't work

Tags: heidisql

Is it possible to find and trace the operation with Heidi sql?

I have already tried about log, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to get a log file of all SQL operations HeidiSQL is doing. This is displayed in the lower SQL log panel.

Also, you can chose which log level messages you want to see there, in Tools > Preferences > Logging.

Also, you can activate logging these message to a log file, by activating "*Write SQL log to file*" in the same dialog.